# How to make different docker-compose mount volumes when has replicas?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have compose file with two dependent services and all works fine. But one has mount volume as

```
volumes:
  - "/web/logs:/usr/src/app/log"
```

and

```
deploy:
   mode: replicated
   replicas: 8 # may be different
```

Thus all replicas use one directory and file name. It is possible to write into different directory or files?

Answer (score 0):

you can add an extra folder under /log,use some variable for the folder name  eg: ip address so it will be unique and can do it automatic.

Comment: It would be very good when i could be  write smth like "/web/logs/$docker.container.name but how can i achieve it?

Comment: its depend on the project you run,you can get the container hostname  from the environment variables,so just set the project log location path  include hostname environment variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I must not modify image, we just can run it, but can define way we can do it.